# Find unique vectors by linear algorithm

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, hash-tables

I was thinking about the homework problem:

> Given $n$ vectors in 3D: $(\mathbf{v_1},\mathbf{v_2},\dots,
>  \mathbf{v_n})$. Their coordinates are positive integers and less than $10^9$.
>   We should split this set into $k$ groups in the way that each two
>   vectors from one group are collinear and from different are not.

So, for example, the set $\big((2,2,2), (3,3,3), (4,5,4), (8,10,8)\big)$ should be split into 2 groups.

If we divide coordinates of each vector $\mathbf{v}$ by $\text{gcd}(x_{\mathbf{v}}, y_{\mathbf{v}}, z_{\mathbf{v}})$. then in each group vectors should be mutually equal and vice versa. So, **the problem is to find the number of unique vectors in the set**.

I need to develop an algorithm to calculate k efficiently.

**1.** I need an algorithm of $O(n)$ expected running time. I know that we could build this groups by sorting, but unfortunately I **banned with sorting** for this problem.

**2.** I suppose that we could build something with hashing and disjoint-set data structure. 
The draft of the solution in this case is following:

1. Considering only x-coordinate we "hash" vectors into $m_x$ buckets by a hash-function taken from a universal set.
2. Each bucket we hash again considering y-coordinate. And again for z-coordinate.
3. For each received bucket we launch an $O(n^2)$ pairwise algorithm and form groups. There we willl need disjoint-set data structure to maintain formed groups.

This solution is simple but requires quite a lot memory. Are there any approaches to solve the problem?

Comment: Please specify whether all vectors will be represented with integral coordinate values. (What about this is _CS_?) Consider polar.

Comment: @greybeard, thank you, statement is edited. All coordinates are integers